# In my anagram problem i dont understand why counter is 16

Tags: javascript, node.js

My problem is about anagrams and this function need to test if var test is identical with original , but in my case counter is 16 , but i don`t understand why. I debugged but is unclearly.Thanks for help!

```
var isAnagram = function(test, original) {   //anagram function test
        let counter=0;
      let test1 = test.toLowerCase().split("");
  let original1=original.toLowerCase().split("");

  const test2= new Set(test1);
  const original2= new Set(original1);

  for(let i of test2)
  {
      for(let j of original2)
      {
          if (test2[i] == original2[j])
          {
              counter++;
          }
      }
  }
  console.log(counter);
   if (counter == test2.length)
   {
       return true;
   }
  return false;


};
console.log(isAnagram("foefet", "toffee")); //case
```

Comment: Your condition seems wrong you are using this `if (test2[i] == original2[j])` that means the `i` and `j` should be the indices but your loops say a different story. `for(let i of test2)` means that `i` will have the value item not the key so in my opinion the condition should be `if (i == j)` or else your code will check the equality between 2 undefined values and it will always be true

Answer (score 1):

- for(let i of Set) already returns the values, not the indices.
- Your algorithm uses these values as index. This always returns undefined
- All the comparisons are true (because undefined === undefined)
- A set of the input string you provided has 4 members (f,o,e,t).
- You iterate over the outer set, then over the inner set. That is 16 comparisons, 16 * true => the counter is increased 16 times.

However, the algorithm won't work even if you fix this - the result will be 4, becasue each letter is counted once (the set only contains one of each).

You need to re-think your algorithm (I'm not going to spoil how as that would ruin your exercise). As a hint, I do not think that sets are a good tool here.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems to be too much complicated, even if you fix it, the result will not be correct because you are removing the duplicated letters by using a `Set`

Here is a possible solution :

```js
function isAnagram (test, original) {
  if (!test || !original || test.length !== original.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  var sortStr = s => s.split('').sort().join('');
  
  return sortStr(test) === sortStr(original);
}

console.log(isAnagram("foefet", "toffee"));
```